# Prove that define topology in ${\mathbb{R}}^2$

Tags: general-topology

I was studying topology and I have problems with this exercise

On the plane ${\mathbb{R}}^2$ consider the family $\tau$ consisting of the $\emptyset$ , ${\mathbb{R}}^2$ and all open discs $\{ x^2 + y^2 < r^2 \}, r > 0$. Prove that $\tau$ defines a topology and determine
the closure of the hyperbola $xy = 1$.

$A1$ For a definition $\emptyset$ and  ${\mathbb{R}}^2$ are in $\tau$.

$A2$ ${\mathbb{R}}^2 \cup$ all open discs $\{ x^2 + y^2 < r^2 \}, r > 0$ it results ${\mathbb{R}}^2$ and ${\mathbb{R}}^2 \in \tau$

$A3$ ${\mathbb{R}}^2 \cap $ all open discs $\{ x^2 + y^2 < r^2 \}, r > 0$ it results all open discs $\{ x^2 + y^2 < r^2 \}, r > 0$ and $\{ x^2 + y^2 < r^2 \}, r > 0 \in \tau$

I have problems determining  the closure of the hyperbola

Thanks

Comment: Your arguments for A2 and A3 are unclear. You need to show that the union of an *arbitrary* collection of open sets is open (not just the union of *all* of the open sets) and that the intersection of two *arbitrary* open sets is open.

Comment: To find the closure of the hyperbola, start with the definition of closure. We need to find the limit points of the hyperbola, i.e. the points $p$ for which every open set containing $p$ contains a point of the hyperbola. Did you get that far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Ok, I understand my error in arguments A2 and A3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof that $\tau$ is a topology is wrong. You were supposed to prove that an union of an arbitrary set of elements of $\tau$ belongs to $\tau$ and that the intersection of finitely many elements of $\tau$ belongs to $\tau$ too.

You know that the closed subsets of $(\Bbb R^2,\tau)$, other than $\emptyset$ and $\Bbb R^2$, are the sets of the form $\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\mid x^2+y^2\geqslant r^2\}$. The smallest of these sets which contains the hyperbola is $\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\mid x^2+y^2\geqslant2\}$. So, this is the closure of the hyperbola.